# What's the best way to disable Jinja2 template caching in bottle.py?

Tags: python, bottle, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 templates with Bottle.py and Google App Engine's dev_appserver for development.  I want the templates to automatically reload on every request (or ideally only when they change), so that I don't have to keep restarting the server.

According to bottle's docs, you're supposed to be able to disable template caching by calling `bottle.debug(True)`.

Jinja still seems to be caching its templates, though.  I believe this to be because of the way the bottle jinja2 adapter is written (it just uses a default Jinja2 loader and doesn't expose many configuration options).

Following the [Jinja2 Docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#loaders), I wrote this custom Loader that I would expect to trigger a template reload every time, but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
import settings
from bottle import jinja2_template
from bottle import Jinja2Template, template as base_template
class AutoreloadJinja2Template(Jinja2Template):
    def loader(self, name):
        def uptodate():
            # Always reload the template if we're in DEVMODE (a boolean flag)
            return not settings.DEVMODE
        fname = self.search(name, self.lookup)
        if fname:
            with open(fname, "rb") as f:
                source = f.read().decode(self.encoding)
            return (source, fname, uptodate)


template = functools.partial(base_template,
    template_adapter=AutoreloadJinja2Template,
    template_lookup = settings.TEMPLATE_PATHS,
    template_settings={
        'auto_reload': settings.DEVMODE
    }
)
```

Templates are still getting cached until I restart dev_appserver.  This must be a fairly common problem.  Does anyone have a solution that works?

UPDATE:

I ended up doing something like:

```
class CustomJinja2Template(Jinja2Template):
   if settings.DEVMODE:
       def prepare(self, *args, **kwargs):
           kwargs.update({'cache_size':0})
           return Jinja2Template.prepare(self, *args, **kwargs)

template = functools.partial(original_template, template_adapter=CustomJinja2Template)
```

This causes the templates to always reload, but only if a python module has been touched.  i.e. if you just edit a template file, the changes won't take affect until you edit one of the python files that imports it.  It seems as if the templates are still being cached somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this issue by ditching bottle's template solutions completely and using pure jinja2. It seems that Jijnja's `FileSystemLoader` is the only one, which can watch for file changes.

I defined new `template` function as follows (it looks for files in `views/`, just like bottle used to):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

if local_settings.DEBUG:
    jinja2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('views/'), cache_size=0)
else:
    jinja2_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('views/'))

def template(name, ctx):
    t = jinja2_env.get_template(name)
    return t.render(**ctx)
```

Then I use it like this:

```
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return template('index.tpl', {'text': "hello"})
```

The difference from bottle's API is that you have to include `.tpl` in file name and you have to pass context variables as dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Bottle caches templates internally (independent from Jinja2 caching). You can disable the cache via `bottle.debug(True)` or `bottle.run(..., debug=True)` or clear the cache with `bottle.TEMPLATES.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't know about bottle.TEMPLATES.clear(), which could come in handy!

I've had bottle.debug(True) set from the beginning of the project, so I'm pretty sure it's been a an issue configuring Jinja's cache.

Comment: What tripped me up is running bottle.debug(True) before bottle.run. bottle.run's debug argument has a default value of False which overwrites bottle.DEBUG if not specified.

Answer (score 3):

The [Environment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment) object in jinja2 has a configuration value for the cache size and, according to the documentation,

> If the cache size is set to 0 templates are recompiled all the time

Have you tried something like this?

```
from jinja2 import Environment
env = Environment(cache_size=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bottle view decorator, you can just do `@view('your_view', cache_size=0)`.

Bottle has a `reloader=True` parameter in server adapter, but I guess it works only with SimpleTemplate. I will try to extend this behaviour to other template engines.

If you want to do it in all your views, maybe you can do something like this:

```
import functools
view = functools.partials(view, cache_size=0)
```

This way, you can do it only when you are in debug mode adding an if statement to this code `if bottle.DEBUG`.

Comment: Downarrowing because the cache_size=0 argument didn't work for me using the view() decorator or the template() function. Also run(reloader=True) throws an error: "local variable 'lockfile' referenced before assignment"

Comment: @arkanciscan this bug probably it is not related with my responseq, but it is okay. Just to you know, I reported your comment as an issue to bottle (https://github.com/defnull/bottle/issues/278). Can you give more details about the bug in github? Which server adapter are you using? Thanks!